# (Drag n drop) Dragula.js not working on revisiting the route (in ember.js app)

Tags: ember.js, drag-and-drop, dragula

I am using `dragula.js` library in an `ember.js` web app.

Things are working fine (able to drag and drop things) until I `revisit the route`, after which `drag and drop just stops working`, that is, can't drag anything that was previously draggable. And there are no js errors in console.
Then, I refresh the page (from any route), it works again.

In short, the *`drag n drop` works only for the first time when the route is visited/loaded*.

Things I tried:

- Verified if the `DOM items` to be drag n dropped, are added to dragula's `config.containers`.
- Tried Rerendering the component from `didInsertElement` element inside the run loop running in `afterRender`.

`didInsertElement(){
      this._super(...arguments);
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, () => {
          let drake = window.dragula(this.getDraggableContainers(), this.get('dragulaConfig'));
          this.set("drake", drake);
    }`

To me, it seems like the `dragula` library is initialized with all the required config, but I am baffled why its NOT working correctly after revisiting the route.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found some time to post an answer to my own question. Yay!

*Reason:*

The node references was invalid or to put in other words, could not be found in the DOM because the node references in my `didInsertElement` hook was pointing to the nodes created in the previous visit to the route and on each subsequent visits to the same route/page the DOM nodes are being recreated by `ember` (ofcourse :)).

*Solution:*

Instead of storing/caching the DOM node references, a *fresh DOM node reference to the required nodes* need to be fetched on each route visit. That way you'll always have valid node references.